# Disable SSL for all traffic originating from China?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ssl, geolocation, great-firewall-of-china

We plan to add SSL site-wide, but there's one major problem. An important segment of our traffic is coming from China, and when SSL is enabled, it creates problems for them in their ability to access, log in, and administer their respective pages on our website.

Is there any way (via apache config, .htaccess config, other) to geofence the SSL cert so that it doesn't load when traffic originates from China? Or in any other way create some "fork" that allow us to circumvent SSL in China. Note that our site is huge, so we're unable to keep two copies of the site.

To be clear, its about anyone behind the Chinese firewall, not about being Chinese. Anyone with a Chinese browser, but in another country outside China should load the page with SSL.

Cheers